# Problem with headers, footers

Tags: header-footer, combine

I have a problem on even pages with header and footer lines. Line shifted towards by text.

Another problem is that heads of `article`'s sections appear on headers and footers, but I don't use it in `fancyhead`, `fancyfoot`.

Have you any ideas?

I use `combine` class for combine articles at single file. 
Structure of article:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{subfig}
...newcommand(for math)
\begin{document}
...title
...text
\end{document}
```

Main code:

```
\documentclass[report,twoside,11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{combine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 

\title{Quantum computers and computing}
\author{Editors}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[CO]{}
\fancyhead[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{QUANTUM COMPUTERS AND COMPUTING}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\newcommand{\authortochead}[1]{%
    \coltocauthor{#1}
    \fancyhead[CE]{#1}
}
\newcommand{\titletochead}[1]{%
    \coltoctitle{#1}
    \fancyhead[CO]{#1}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{papers}

\titletochead{Paper 1}
\authortochead{A. N. Author}
    \import{article1}
\end{papers}

\begin{papers}
\cleardoublepage
\titletochead{Paper 2}
\authortochead{A. N. Other}
    \import{article1}

\end{papers}

%% Acknowledgements etc

\end{document}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem? I understand that you may thing this is provided in the post. However, from the community's perspective and to speed up any possible solutions, it helps tremendously if you provide a copy-and-paste-able structure, rather than code snippets.